# Multiple dropbox accounts on one PC?

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing

Is there a way to have a PC connect to multiple dropbox accounts?

I have a personal dropbox account which I use to sync files across multiple PCs and that all works fine.

However, someone who wishes to share documents with me (and several others) has suggested using dropbox to share the documents. They've setup a new dropbox account for just this purpose but I can't see how I can use this without unlinking my computer form my account.

Any ideas?

Comment: So the new account is for you to use? Or for the other person?

Comment: Run dropbox off a USB drive?

Comment: wonder why I lost two. It wasn't really a bad solution. Just close the existing dropbox on the tray and run the other from the USB.

Comment: There's a tutorial here; http://www.semi-legitimate.com/sls/blog/36-tech-tips/54-multiple-dropbox-instances Hope this helps.

Comment: Why USB? The issue is not storage space. Might as well just have two separate folders. I don't think it's trivial to accomplish anyway.

Comment: Because it lets you make install dropbox with a separate login? I'm not talking about space here.

Comment: As Whitingx's answer eludes to, it's far from a trivial process.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Dropbox supports sharing content across multiple accounts.

- On the Dropbox website, using the
  account you wish to share from,
  create a new folder (e.g. "my
  project")
- In the top toolbar, select "Invite to
  folder", enter the email addresses
  for the recipients (make sure it's
  the email they already use for their
  Dropbox account).
- Each recipient will get an email
  asking if they wish to accept the
  share. When they do, the new folder
  (e.g. "my project") will appear and
  synch in their personal account.
- The recipient can reorganise as they
  see fit.  just move the location of
  the folder in their account (say to
  move it into a "shared" folder or a
  "Projects for Matt" folder) - it
  won't affect anyone else who is
  sharing it (only changes to the
  contents of the folder will)

Comment: Good idea, but make sure everyone has enough storage space to accommodate the new shared folder.  Some users keep themselves closer to the storage limit than others.

Answer (score 10):

This is how I get around it

1. Create a new windows account
2. Create a shortcut to DropBox on your desktop
3. Hold shift and Right click the shortcut and click Run As Different User
4. Type YourPcName\YourNewAccount for UserName and your password
5. A new DropBox window will open up now and ask for your email/password.

You should now have two dropboxes in your task bar.

Answer (score 1):

You might setup a new account in the name of the project as a kind of 'master' account to keep the shared files under the control of the team, not any one individual, then using the web interface manage the folder sharing. This way the shared files will be synced to your account automatically (no need to mess with multiple desktop accounts).

But otherwise, as long as each user has there own account, I don't see any reason for extra accounts. Just select a folder to share and then add the users to begin sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can share folders with any number of people.

Right click any folder in your dropbox account, and choose "DropBox" and "Share this folder".

You'll be taken to a webpage where you can enter the email addresses of the people you need to share the folder with.

Everyone you're sharing with will need a dropbox account, but there's no need to create a separate "just for the project" dropbox account.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a app named MultCloud could do this.
https://www.multcloud.com

Site mentions “Combine free space all together to form a larger space” (and, since mention of `free`, the app itself is also) and “Doesn't need logging into multiple cloud accounts, MultCloud will combine these cloud drives together to manage just by logging once, and easily access all supported cloud files..”

One recommendation there explains some of the process: “In the past, if I want to move files from DropBox to Box.net, the files have to download from DropBox and then uploaded to Box.net. For large or numerous files, this is inconvenient and time-consuming. Copying a file or folder between services is as easy as drag-and-drop…”