# How to use two Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple dropbox accounts on one PC?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2183/multiple-dropbox-accounts-on-one-pc)

I have a personal Dropbox and I have special dropbox that I'm using with a friend like a SVN server(to hold code). How can I easly switch between those two?

Comment: Consider sharing folders instead of sharing the password of the same dropbox account..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look similar to the question answered here;

[Multiple dropbox accounts on one PC?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2183/multiple-dropbox-accounts-on-one-pc)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

Not directly answering your question but you should consider using a [Distributed Version Control System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Version_Control_System) rather than SVN. Have a look at [Git](http://git-scm.com/) with [GitHub](https://github.com/), or [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) with [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)...

Comment: Definitely a better choice for your situation.

Comment: + bitbucket has unlimited storage for less than 5 people..

Comment: i disagree. it sucks, there is also closed source code you guys. coding is sometimes for money.

Comment: @0101, with BitBucket you can have a private repository so it will be available to assigned people only

Answer (score 1):

From the Dropbox website:

At the moment you can only run one installation of Dropbox on a single computer and it can only be linked to a single account.

Accessing another account from a computer where Dropbox is already installed (or any computer, for that matter) is as easy as logging in as another user through the Dropbox website.

Otherwise, you can link accounts together by creating shared folders. Shared folders are designed to allow you to sync files between multiple accounts.

**For Our Advanced Users**

Another option is to use a different Dropbox account for each user login on your computer. While this technically means you can have several Dropbox folders on the same computer, you will have to switch between each user account to take advantage of Dropbox's syncing features. This method is best for groups or families that have individual Dropbox accounts and use unique user logins on the same computer.

[Source](http://www.dropbox.com/help/61)

Answer (score 1):

Your could share the SVN folder from the dedicated drobox account with both of your personal dropbox accounts. This way both of you could log in with your respective accounts and sync your personal data and SVN data by using the same dropbox instance.
**A word of warning:** If both of you commit to (or change in any other way) the repo at the same time this could seriously mess up the repository. SVN makes some assumptions about the file system that dropbox was not designed to provide. I would use a free repository hosting service from [this](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/6651/8609) question.

Comment: i use git, i think its better here.